# Testing using time helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using the standard tools included in Rails 6 for testing. It's a very simple test, but it seems the freeze_time is not working, and the error code is quite difficult to discern a cause from.

Here is the test I am executing:

[image]

Here is the error after running the test:

[image]

Comment: Please(!) post the actual text content of your code and error messages as is described in the StackOverflow guidelines. Do not simply post screenshots! As it is, I had to hand-type the code in my answer when I should have been able to copy yours to begin with.

Comment: So, are you ever going to post the real text? This question will live on forever, and someone else might have a better answer. They will want that text to copy from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new `Person` the value for `created_at` should be set (assuming it has `timestamps` applied), but since you're getting `nil` instead it is almost certain your `Person` creation fails. Likely due to validations errors when it tries to save. You could look at the model's error entries to be sure.

To get the error to show up for viewing:

```
class PersonTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test 'created at matches current time' do
    freeze_time
    assert_equal(Time.current, Person.create!.created_at)
  end
end
```

If it is a validation error, you can bypass those:

```
class PersonTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test 'created at matches current time' do
    freeze_time
    person = Person.new.save(validate: false)
    assert_equal(Time.current, person.created_at)
  end
end
```

There are two things wrong with this though.

1. You want to avoid saving to the DB if at all possible during tests to keep them performant.
2. You are actually testing Rails's built-in functionality here. This is a test you should not be performing. There may be a better test to check that the Rails `timestamps` have been applied to your `Person` model, but that's not one I've ever written before (and I write tests for *everything*). There is no way to accidentally eliminate the `timestamps` in a simple commit (it takes an entire accidental migration), so testing for their existence feels way overkill.

Comment: Thanks Ben, thats a lot of helpful information. The fix you suggested was throwing PG errors about missing fields. I struggled getting this to work, it seemed like it should have been easy. 

The information you provided was very helpful and I did find a solution when working with a test fixture and then freezing time, setting the created_at to Time.current and then asserting.

Comment: "That value is typically set only after you save the Person" - `create` does save the object and set the timestamps. The real problem here is OP is trying to create an invalid record, so the validations prevent the write from happening. He should do a `Person.create!.created_at` instead.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thank you for the reality check. I've edited the answer for correctness.